# no viable alternative at input for simple grammar

Tags: antlr4

I am attempting to create a parser for a simple DSL using ANTLR 4.  I am getting "no viable alternative at input" from my test and ANTLRWorks.

The grammar:

```
grammar Test;
process: action ('|' action)* ;
action: (filter) | (transform) | (log);
transform: 'transform' '(' ( ('name' '=' transformName)|('regex' '=' regex)) ')' ;
transformName: NAME;
filter: 'filter' '(' ( ('name' '=' filterName)|('regex' '=' regex)) ')' ;
filterName: NAME;
regex: QUOTEDSTRING;
log: 'log' ('(' 'name' '=' logName (',' 'level' '=' logLevel)? ')')? ;
logName: NAME;
logLevel: NAME;
NAME : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.]* ;
STRING : (~["])+ ;
QUOTEDSTRING: '"' STRING '"';
WS :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip ;
```

The input:

```
log (name=mylog,level=debug)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lexer tokens are not disjunct:

```
NAME : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.]* ;
STRING : (~["])+ ;
QUOTEDSTRING: '"' STRING '"';
WS :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip ;
```

ANTLR first processes these rules on the input. A Token is the longest Sequence matched by any of these rules. Since `STRING` subsumes almost everything (except double quotes):

`log (name=mylog,level=debug)` is matched as STRING, because it matches sequences of characters, whitespaces, parentheses and equal operators. No other token type gets such long matches, so STRING is preferred.

To solve it, make your lexer rules disjunct:

```
NAME : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.]* ;
QUOTEDSTRING: '"' (~["])+? '"';
WS :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip ;
```

QUOTEDSTRING will only match long sequences starting and ending with double quotes. Your line will not contain any STRING.

Comment: I probably should have figured this out on my own, but sometimes it takes another set of eyes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing the ANTLR4 syntax and ANTLR3 syntax (supported by ANTLRWorks)

Try something like this instead

```
grammar Test;
eval    :process EOF;
process :action ('|' action)*;
action  :(filter) | (transform) | (log);
transform   :'transform' '(' ( ('name' '=' transformName)|('regex' '=' regex)) ')' ;
transformName   :NAME;
filter  :'filter' '(' ( ('name' '=' filterName)|('regex' '=' regex)) ')' ;
filterName  :NAME;
regex   :QUOTEDSTRING;
log :'log' ('(' 'name' '=' logName (',' 'level' '=' logLevel)? ')')? ;
logName :NAME;
logLevel:NAME;
WS  
    :   (
             ' '
        |    '\r'
        |    '\t'
        |    '\u000C'
        |    '\n'
        ) 
            {
                skip();
            }          
    ;
QUOTEDSTRING    :'"' NAME '"';
NAME    :('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;
```

Seems to work this way

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to NAME or WS?  I got the above from The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference.

Comment: And ANTLRWorks was designed to work with ANTLR3. Have you tried my example?